# Visualizing a Jasper Report/JXRML without compiling it via Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a computer that is provided by the company I work for, to "print" a Jasper report I understand that I need to compile my Java code. It's a big project now and to run the application I need an IBM plugin that is currently not working, and the company is working on fixing it for a couple months already, without success.

Is there any other way that I can check a Jasper Report to edit it without sending it all the way to PROD to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any easy findable answer for this on Stack Overflow. I did some digging and came around Jasper Studio. It seems to exist a Community Edition which is free, and I'll try it out.

Documenting this answer here because I've inherit a project with Jasper and knew nothing about it, and their site is a bit cryptic/not very straightforward regarding all of it. So hopefully this will be helpful to someone else in the future.